# The best mysql_fetch_array use

Tags: php, mysql

What is the best use (to save machine resources) for mysql_fetch_array:

```
$listidsquery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM database") or die(mysql_error());
 while($listidsres=mysql_fetch_array($listidsquery)){
        results;
        }
```

or

```
 while($listidsres=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM database"))){
        results;
        }
```

Thanks.

Comment: _Never_ nest `mysql_query()` inside a fetch call.  If the query fails, you'll get a fatal error from `mysql_fetch_array()`. Your first example is the correct method, but you should also check `if ($results)` to be sure the query succeeded.

Comment: Any reason you're not using mysqli? The functions you are using are being deprecated.

Comment: Please, don't use mysql_* functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, here is [good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first snippet is the correct one, and will yield superior performance.  The first one sets a mysql resultset resource to `$listidres` - a resource is a simple integer value.  It will therefore not consume any significant additional resources.

The second snippet is not correct at all.  It will re-execute the query for each iteration of the loop (and will therefore likely result in an infinite loop).

As was stated in the comments above, both snippets are using the `mysql` library, which is EOL.  You should move to `mysqli` instead.